# d3 version 4 issue with rectangle and text

Tags: d3.js

This method works in v3 to append rectangles with text inside but fails in v4.  I getting an error message "read property 'querySelectorAll'" but it may not be relevant to this piece of code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
group = vis.selectAll(".rectangle")
         .data(data); 


gEnter = group.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "rectangle")
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return d.colour; });


gEnter.append("rect") 
  .attr("class", "rectband");


group.selectAll(".rectband")
     .attr("width", 18)
     .attr("height", 18)
     .style("opacity", .5) 
     .style("stroke", "black")
     .style("cursor", "move");


svgEnter = group.enter()
      .append("svg")
      .attr("height", 18)
      .attr("class", "interval")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("x", 20)
      .attr("y", 20);

svgEnter.append("text")
                .attr("class", "intervalLabel")
                .attr("x", 6)
                .attr("y", 14)
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .text(function (d) { return (d.name); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code *kinda* works but your text elements are on top of each other and in an `svg` container that's not wide enough to show their content.

Anyway, if you make your svg wider, the text shows just fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
  
    var vis = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 400)
      .attr('height', 400);
  
    group = vis.selectAll(".rectangle")
      .data([
        {
          colour: 'red',
          name: 'one'
        },
        {
          colour: 'green',
          name: 'two'
        }
      ]);


    gEnter = group.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "rectangle")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.colour;
      });

    gEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "rectband")
      .merge(gEnter)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("opacity", .5)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("cursor", "move");

    svgEnter = group.enter()
      .append("svg")
      .attr("height", 18)
      .attr("class", "interval")
      .attr("width", 30)
      .attr("x", 20)
      .attr("y", 20);

    svgEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", "intervalLabel")
      .attr("x", 6)
      .attr("y", 14)
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .text(function(d) {
        return (d.name);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: However,if you change to v3 (<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>)  it draws the rectangle but not in v4?

Comment: @user3359706, I understand now.  The enter/update/exit pattern has changed in v4.  You now need to explicitely [merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) the enter and update selecitons, see update above.

Comment: @user3359706, here's your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/rm16L13s/3/) for v4.

Comment: That fiddle is running v3.  When I changed to v4 in local browser it still fails   for some reason?

Comment: My mistake.  The updated fiddle is working as expected.  Thanks.